# Gradle module and git submodule

Tags: android, git, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I have a library project called toolkit with two modules `core` and `database`, with this config:

settings.gradle

```
include ':core'
include ':database'
```

core build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:0.7.+'
    compile files('libs/flurry-3.4.0.jar')
}
```

database build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':core')
}
```

it`s ok when run my tests at this library project, but i want add this library as a git submodule on other project, this project have the follow configuration:

settings.gradle

```
include ':app-tablet'
include 'libraries:float-hint'
include 'libraries:toolkit:core'
include 'libraries:toolkit:database'
include 'libraries:twoway-view:TwoWayView'
```

app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1@jar'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1@jar'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:float-hint')
    compile project(':libraries:porquenao-toolkit:core')
    compile project(':libraries:porquenao-toolkit:database')
    compile project(':libraries:twoway-view:TwoWayView')
}
```

and when I try compile i get the follow:

```
$  gradlew assembleDebug -d

12:10:46.283 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
12:10:46.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
12:10:46.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
12:10:46.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file '/path/libraries/toolkit/database/build.gradle' line: 16
12:10:46.286 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
12:10:46.286 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
12:10:46.286 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating project ':libraries:toolkit:database'.
12:10:46.287 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Project with path ':core' could not be found in project ':libraries:toolkit:database'.
12:10:46.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... more
12:10:46.308 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
12:10:46.308 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
```

I know the problem is about paths `:core` and `libraries:toolkit:core` but how solve this appropriately?

Comment: shouldn't your database build contain compile `project(':libraries:toolkit:core')`

Comment: @njzk2 no because I want use this toolkit in future with other projects, and this other projects can have different paths than `libraries:toolkit`... also the androidTest on toolkit need found the core with `:core`

Comment: then I would think that you possibly should include `core` as a submodule of `database`?

Comment: @njzk2 this probably works 'if the gradle get no problems with two projects equals, the core used by app and the core used by database', but I really want use the same git repository because the projects are really small, in future the idea is separate in differents projects, but not today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a naming issue your apps gradle files.

The settings.gradle has:

`include 'libraries:toolkit:core'`

And the build.gradle has:

```
compile project(':libraries:porquenao-toolkit:core')
```

Assuming you fix this up, you will still have an error.

The database module will be trying to compile *":core"*, but when used in the app, the core module has a different path: *":libraries:porquenao-toolkit:core"*

One way to work around this is to include the core library as ":core" in both projects, but give it a different project path.

Your settings.gradle files would look like:

**Toolkit:**

```
include ':core'
project(':core').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 'core')
```

**App:**

```
include ':core'
project(':core').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 'libraries/porquenao-toolkit/core')
```